# Least privileges to view all users in sys.database_principals

Tags: sql, sql-server

What least privileges are required by a user to view all database users? I have tried granting

```
SELECT/ALTER on sys.database_principals TO TestUser
```

at the database level but no luck. I have also tried granting

```
VIEW SERVER STATE/VIEW ANY DATABASE for TestUser login
```

and no luck. The only way I made work to assign syadmin server role to the TestUser Login, but certainly I don't wand to do that. I am using SQL server 2014.

Comment: You might check the documentation. :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for the link. GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO TestUser worked.

Comment: If the reqired permissions are more than you want to grant directly, you could create a proc, grant exec permissions on the proc to the user, and [sign the proc with a certificate](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) that has the permissions.